# How can I access something like Task Manager in Windows to kill processes that are hogging memory?

Tags: ram

When I was using three windows in Chromium and two windows in Firefox my system suddenly hung while I was switching between them.

In Windows I used to open task manager and close a specific window which was stuck.

How to do this in Ubuntu?

Comment: If you want to do the same just open the system monitor and kill the process. But it would be much better if you actually troubleshoot or avoid the problem in the first place.

Comment: Pls help me how to do this in 16.04 LTS version. Pls don't tell its outdated cannot answer . Im unable to upgrade ram of my laptop to go for latest versions due to lockdown in my country .

Comment: I'm checking , 24601. Thanks

Comment: I checked, 24601. Even I'm unable to move cursor to open terminal . At that time what to do?

Comment: @sivasdpi Ctrl+Alt+T

Answer (score 1):

Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and you will get into a login terminal.

Enter your login details.

Enter `sudo ps -A` - this lists all processes running on the computer.
Write down the process ID - PID of the stuck process.

Enter `sudo kill PID` where PID is the process ID of your stuck process.

Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to resume the graphic mode.

In case the graphic mode is stuck enter in the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> screen `sudo service lightdm restart`.